# Go back 1 history but DONT run any query or whatever

Tags: javascript, button, execution, back

This is a pretty nice script to go back 1 history:

```
<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Back" onClick="history.go(-1);>
```

But the problem is, if I executed any query or whatever on let's say addnewcustomer.php and than I link to companyview.php and using this code I go back to addnewcustomer.php, it executes the same query all over (or browser gives me a warning and have to hit F5).
How to avoid this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to avoid these situations would be to:

1. not change any data on GET requests, instead manipulate only on POST requests.
2. implement [post-to-get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303) (303) redirect after any data manipulation.

You should then be good